# Wired Networking Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, ethernet

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 and then 17.04 and lost wired networking in the process. It was fine 4 hours ago before upgrading. I can connect to WiFi but Ethernet Network is grayed out in my Network Management menu. 
Here is the output of ifconfig -a

```
ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e8:40:f2:81:23:fa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 479  bytes 114309 (114.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 479  bytes 114309 (114.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::367c:5f4:624a:57f5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9c:b7:0d:e0:54:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18802  bytes 13005919 (13.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19310  bytes 4364068 (4.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If, as this site
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wired-connect.html
describes, I need to manually set up my IPV4, where do I find the values to use?

Comment: I have an old 32 bit Dell on the same network running Lubuntu that I upgraded to 17.04 from 16.10 on Thurs. It has no wired networking problem.

Comment: Solved!! I added: auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp    to my /etc/network/interfaces  file, restarted networking and  .. bingo!!!!

Answer (score 9):

Edit file `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` and change it's content from:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

to :

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:ethernet,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

And then run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 2):

exactly same problem here. Solved with creating an empty file:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

GR