# Wireless and LAN keep disconnecting with Ubuntu (Mate) 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, disconnect

**EDIT**

The problem also exists on my other laptop, which has a different ethernet card. I assume the problem isn't Ubuntu per se.

Noteworthy though is that internet with Ubuntu works at my other home. And internet here works on both laptops booting Windows.

This problem becomes more complicated each time I come closer to a solution. Anybody has an idea what could be causing this strange behavior?

**Problem**

*Wireless:* I am connected to my home network, everything works fine for 30 seconds but shortly after the connection drops with the following error in chrome:

```
server DNS address could not be found.

Try:
Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG
```

When I re-connect it works again for about 30 seconds, this is an infinite cycle.

*LAN:* At first my wired connection wasn't working at all. After a lot of googling I got it to work with this code from the following thread:
[LAN not working on 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906103/lan-not-working-on-17-04)

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

However the wired connection now has the same issue as wireless. It also stops working after a short time with the same error in chrome. However, with the wired connection I can still visit, and browse through all pages of websites I've loaded in the same session. This leads me to the conclusion that new DNS'es simply stop working after a given time.

**Details**

sudo lshw -class network

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 24:0a:64:2b:be:83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.10.0-35-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: ac:22:0b:6b:ec:86
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
```

lspci | grep Ethernet

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

**ifconfig**

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:22:0b:6b:ec:86  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4839 errors:0 dropped:12 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4973 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:626953 (626.9 KB)  TX bytes:451800 (451.8 KB)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16978 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16978 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1187497 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:1187497 (1.1 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:0a:64:2b:be:83  
          inet addr:192.168.2.9  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ec5c:5586:a720:a516/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:96868 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69837 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:87915699 (87.9 MB)  TX bytes:11537092 (11.5 MB)
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home
```

ls -la /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 jun  3  2015 /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nvram                  16384  0
msr                    16384  0
ccm                    20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              172032  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             200704  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    90112  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
cryptd                 24576  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 20480  0
arc4                   16384  2
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
ath9k                 147456  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
mac80211              782336  1 ath9k
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
cfg80211              602112  4 mac80211,ath9k,ath,ath9k_common
snd                    77824  17 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
lpc_ich                24576  0
shpchp                 36864  0
mei_me                 40960  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
mac_hid                16384  0
asus_wireless          16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
fjes                   77824  0
psmouse               139264  0
i915                 1449984  8
video                  40960  2 asus_wmi,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        151552  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
alx                    45056  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mdio                   16384  1 alx
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
wmi                    16384  1 asus_wmi
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  4
libahci                32768  1 ahci
drm                   352256  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
```

lspci -n | egrep '0200|0280' | awk '{print$3}'

```
168c:0032
1969:1091
```

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE186H [1a3b:1186]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
--
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1043:14c7]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
```

rfkill list all

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**iwlist wlan0 scan**

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

*/var/log/syslog* pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/ytY7z4QU

Comment: Inspect at `/var/log/syslog`, maybe there you'll see any reasons. If you pastebin a sample, we can help you

Comment: Alright, here you go: https://pastebin.com/ytY7z4QU @Redbob