# Ethernet cable suddenly appears "disconnected" on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, ethernet

Ethernet connection worked fine for years under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS until today when it failed after boot and ever since, resulting "disconnected".

**What I've tried so far:**

- changing the cable -> *failed*
- switching port on the router -> *failed*
- installing another driver version (r8168 instead of r8169), as seen [here](https://www.unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/) -> *failed* (on the other hand, the default driver worked fine until this morning)
- solutions to ["device not managed"](https://askubuntu.com/q/906103/873160) -> *failed*

**Some useful outputs**

```
~$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: ens33
   version: 01
   serial: 00:21:97:18:f3:1a
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:26 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:febff000-febfffff memory:febc0000-febdffff

~$ lspci -vnn | grep -A8 Ethernet
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [1019:8168]
Physical Slot: 33
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
Memory at febff000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Expansion ROM at febc0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169

~$ ifconfig -a
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 00:21:97:18:f3:1a  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      Byte RX:0 (0.0 B)  Byte TX:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Loopback locale  
      indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
      indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:4820 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4820 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1 
      Byte RX:356896 (356.8 KB)  Byte TX:356896 (356.8 KB)

~$ ethtool ens33
Settings for ens33:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  Not reported
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: No
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: off
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: no

~$ dmesg | grep -e ens33 -e r8169
[    1.504743] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    1.505223] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168b/8111b at 0xffffc90000788000, 00:21:97:18:f3:1a, XID 18000000 IRQ 26
[    1.505228] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 4080 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    1.596385] r8169 0000:02:00.0 ens33: renamed from eth0
[   42.533109] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens33: link is not ready
[   42.564085] r8169 0000:02:00.0 ens33: link down
[   42.564160] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens33: link is not ready
```

I'm out of options, any idea/suggestions on how to get my Ethernet connection back to work is appreciated.

Comment: Hardware failure? What does the status LED on the network card say? And its strange that you only get `10Mbit/s`.

Comment: Have you tried to follow this? https://medium.com/@lgobinath/no-ethernet-connection-in-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18-with-realtek-rtl8111-8168-8411-7ae2779dc9b8

Comment: @MatsK yes, I already tried to install r8168 driver instead of r8169, nothing changed.

Comment: `10Mbit/s` is the same output I get on my laptop (with working eth connection) when eth cable is not plugged in

Comment: Strange that autoneg is off. See if `sudo ethtool -s ens33 autoneg on` makes anything happen. If not, have you tried an older kernel?

Comment: @KenSharp I tried to enable autoneg, nothing changed. Even booting Ubuntu live from USB didn't help.

Comment: That definitely sounds like hardware failure. They do fail, sometimes.