# LAN cable not detecting ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, ethernet cable is being not detected. Previously it worked fine.
Here is the output of `ifconfig`.

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 13682  bytes 1147280 (1.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13682  bytes 1147280 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.xxxx  netmask 255.255.xxx  broadcast 172.1.xxxx
        inet6 fe80::d0c: prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 48:e2:44:d0:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 58110  bytes 14571654 (14.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 34695
        TX packets 3998  bytes 610656 (610.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17
```

Comment: Please edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1201642/edit ) your pst and show us the results of `sudo lshw -c network`

Comment: @waltinator issue resolve thanks anyway. flagged to close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LAN not working on 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906103/lan-not-working-on-17-04)