# Ethernet adapter was disable on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, 17.04

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 but I don't know why my Ethernet interface was disabled.

I  tried `lshw -C network` and it shows this:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 00:21:cc:cd:28:8f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:28 memory:f2500000-f251ffff memory:f253b000-f253bfff ioport:6080(size=32)
```

How I can enable it?

Comment: What are results of `ip l `?

Comment: `enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
`

Comment: Try with `sudo ip l s dev enp0s25 up`. Make sure that ethernet cable is connected.

Comment: Very welcome. :-)

Comment: This question is an almost duplicate from another one too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/905552/wired-networking-ubuntu-17-04

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here is how to fix this problem.

Edit file */usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf* and change it's content from :

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

To :

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:ethernet,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

And then run :

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

That's all.

Comment: In case /usr/lib/NetworkManager doesnt exist, you have to install network-manager first

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try to  check  NetworkManager.conf for `managed=false` and change it to `true` as described in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1043244/277898

Comment: On newer Ubuntu versions the original line is different. I would suggest not to replace the line but to append `,except:type:ethernet` to the end of the line to get ethernet back!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to fix the "Unmanaged" device problem. I had to restart the service manager differently, though: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`. I'm on ubuntu 21.10, but I'm pretty sure that this is the right syntax for current LTS, and probably  1 or 2 versions behind.  Cheers

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed it for me... twice. After some updates (presumably) this fix undid itself.

Comment: This issue was driving me nuts, and I finally typed the correct search terms to bring me to this answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

My Ethernet was also disabled after I upgraded from LTS 16.04 to 16.10 then to 17.04. I was able to resolve by manually doing the following:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up 
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Comment: This helped! But after reboot I again have to type this to get a connection. Is there a proper way to configure this automatically?

Comment: @Socrates The first solution has worked for me to make it automatically https://askubuntu.com/a/909185/170833 . AFAIK it's doing internally a similar thing (starting the interface and calling dhcp client after it)

Comment: @morhook This requires installing additional software 'network-manager' which is not installed by default on ubuntu server

Comment: I'm not sure how to schedule this commands via configuration on `ubuntu server` without `network-manager`

Comment: On 18.04 server (new install) the NIC was disabled... this allowed me to bring the NIC up and get on the network without network-manager being installed, but the NIC would get disabled again on reboot. Once I was online I installed network-manager and used this solution for a permanent fix: https://askubuntu.com/a/909185/283005

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete all in /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
2. Change [ifupdown] managed=false to true in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
3. restart with sudo service network-manager restart

Answer (score 1):

When I upgraded to 17.04 this network manager file was blocking my system from automatically managing my devices.

/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf

Content:

[keyfile]

unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

I commented it all out, rebooted, and everything works fine now. It can also be deleted.

Reference: [Network Manager refusing to manage wired interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838865/network-manager-refusing-to-manage-wired-interfaces)

Answer (score 1):

Other's replies solve the problem, but you should **not** edit the system file `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` since your changes could be overwritten during the next upgrade, and you probably won't remember which is the file involved.

Create a new file instead: `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` which overrides the first one.
Make it empty or comment its content with the hash symbol:

```
[keyfile]
# unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```