# Intermitent ethernet connection, Destination Host Unreachable on ping 1/3 of the time

Tags: ethernet, ping, wired

I'm having intermitent issues connecting to the internet only when connecting my DELL XPS 15 through a wired connection. These are very fast "working not working status" as you can see by the ping logs.

Wifi is fine. I'm using an usb-c to ethernet adaptor, (RTL8152B). I have no issues when connecting on windows (i have a dual boot set up) so it is likely to be a ubuntu issue. Running Ubunutu 20.04, Desktop version.

When `$ ping 8.8.8.8` I get:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=86 ttl=52 time=1057 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=87 ttl=52 time=36.6 ms
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=88 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=89 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=90 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=91 ttl=52 time=1060 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=92 ttl=52 time=40.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=93 ttl=52 time=31.3 ms
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=94 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=98 ttl=52 time=37.3 ms
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=99 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=100 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=101 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=102 ttl=52 time=793 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=103 ttl=52 time=31.1 ms
```

when doing `$ arp -a`

I sometimes get:

```
_gateway (192.168.0.1) at <incomplete> on enx00e04c361b34
```

or this:

```
_gateway (192.168.0.1) at e8:20:e2:02:11:03 [ether] on enx00e04c361b34
```

when running `$ ifconfig` I sometimes get this:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:ce:97:30:43  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx00e04c361b34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2804:14c:3f84:133::1000  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2804:14c:3f84:133:d85b:b67a:a473:a6df  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::e28d:f022:de61:3e7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2804:14c:3f84:133:16f1:7519:fac8:2c48  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:e0:4c:36:1b:34  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10534  bytes 3590043 (3.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15516  bytes 2482112 (2.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 32949  bytes 3137597 (3.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32949  bytes 3137597 (3.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and sometimes:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:4a:7f:1b:c8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx00e04c361b34: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::e28d:f022:de61:3e7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2804:14c:3f84:133:4d1:809b:bb7c:1fb9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2804:14c:3f84:133:16f1:7519:fac8:2c48  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:e0:4c:36:1b:34  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2850  bytes 1056513 (1.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4563  bytes 651079 (651.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5533  bytes 547723 (547.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5533  bytes 547723 (547.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**NOTE here** that enx00e04c361b34: flags=4099 is not RUNNING anymore. I'm not quite sure what that means.

When doing `$ sudo lshw -c network` i get:

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: wlp59s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:fd:d3:63
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-7626-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:149 memory:ed200000-ed3fffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: enx00e04c361b34
       serial: 00:e0:4c:36:1b:34
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.10.11 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.22 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:ce:97:30:43
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

I tried re-installing the drivers on Realtek website for Linux but the issue persists. 
I turned the modem on and off several times, along with rebooting Ubuntu and it worked once a few days ago. However, after replugging the cable, the intermittent issue came back.

I also tried resetting the network manager, and adding the logical name to `/etc/network/interfaces` by writing the following (as suggested on [Wired Ethernet not working Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049302/wired-ethernet-not-working-ubuntu-18-04)):

```
auto enx00e04c361b34
iface enx00e04c361b34 inet dhcp
```

and then running the interface:

```
sudo ifup enx00e04c361b34
```

But that did not work either.

---

Some additional information regarding the Network Manager logs:

```
sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
```

gives me the following warnings right out of the bet:

```
May 15 18:47:55 linux NetworkManager[829]: <warn>  [1589579275.9905] config: unknown key 'wifi.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.>
May 15 18:47:55 linux NetworkManager[829]: <warn>  [1589579275.9905] config: unknown key 'ethernet.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/c>
```

latter also:

```
May 15 18:47:56 linux NetworkManager[829]: <warn>  [1589579276.8992] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
```

After turning off the wifi and leaving it only with the wired connection I have the following logs that basicly repeat...:

```
May 15 18:55:02 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579702.7769] device (enx00e04c361b34): DHCPv6 lease renewal requested
May 15 18:55:02 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579702.7770] dhcp6 (enx00e04c361b34): canceled DHCP transaction
May 15 18:55:02 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579702.7770] dhcp6 (enx00e04c361b34): state changed bound -> done
May 15 18:55:02 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579702.7783] dhcp6 (enx00e04c361b34): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 15 18:55:03 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579703.8939] dhcp6 (enx00e04c361b34): option dhcp6_name_servers   => '2804:14c:3f10:672:189:7:40:42 2804:14c:3f10:672:189:7:40:47'
May 15 18:55:03 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579703.8940] dhcp6 (enx00e04c361b34): option ip6_address          => '2804:14c:3f84:133::1000'
May 15 18:55:03 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579703.8940] dhcp6 (enx00e04c361b34): state changed unknown -> bound
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8474] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option dhcp_lease_time      => '3600'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8474] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option domain_name_servers  => '189.7.40.42 189.7.40.47'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8475] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option expiry               => '1589583304'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8475] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option ip_address           => '192.168.0.22'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8475] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8475] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_domain_name => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8475] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8476] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_domain_search => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8476] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_host_name  => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8476] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8476] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8476] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8477] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8477] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8477] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8477] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_root_path  => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8478] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_routers    => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8478] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_static_routes => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8478] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8478] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_time_offset => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8478] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option requested_wpad       => '1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8479] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option routers              => '192.168.0.1'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8479] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
May 15 18:55:04 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579704.8479] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): state changed unknown -> bound
May 15 18:55:07 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579707.9742] device (enx00e04c361b34): carrier: link connected
May 15 18:55:07 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579707.9756] device (enx00e04c361b34): DHCPv4 lease renewal requested
May 15 18:55:07 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579707.9951] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): canceled DHCP transaction
May 15 18:55:07 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579707.9952] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): state changed bound -> done
May 15 18:55:07 linux NetworkManager[5625]: <info>  [1589579707.9962] dhcp4 (enx00e04c361b34): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Look at the logs - they reflect dynamic system behaviour. `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`