# Unmanaged devices Ubuntu 18.04 with installed openbox

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, ethernet

I have installed on ubuntu 18.04 server edition manually the `xorg`, `nm-applet` and `openbox` wm and over the `~/.config/openbox/autostart` I have the following settings:

```
dbus-launch nm-applet&
lxpanel &
```

But when I try to click on network-manager icon I get the error:

> Ethernet Network
>   Device Not Managed

So I tried any trick shown in the following questions:

- [Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)
- [network manager says "device not managed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)

After having installed `ifupdown`:

```
sudo apt install ifupdown
```

and purging netplan:

```
sudo apt purge nplan
```

But I fail to make the `nm-applet` to manage my ethernet device. Can you help me?

## Edit 1:

I reinstalled the `nplan` and I put the following configuration into `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

But I still have probs to tame it.

Comment: Is there a typo in `dbus-launch nm-applet&`? Shouldn't there be a space before `&`?

Comment: nm-applet witn with & stuck to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is the `netplan` network management. In order to fix that switch into `ifupdown` by typing the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop networkd-dispatcher
sudo systemctl disable networkd-dispatcher
sudo systemctl mask networkd-dispatcher
sudo apt-get purge nplan netplan.io
sudo apt-get install ifupdown
```

And make them managed by following the answers seen in the following questions:

- [Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)
- [network manager says "device not managed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)