# Ubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop: since last upgrade : Wired unmanaged with the previous network configuration files

Tags: networking, 18.04, upgrade, netplan, wired

Last evening I made the requested packages upgrade for Ubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop. But now I'm not able to connect to the network anymore with the previous network configuration files.
These are the packages upgraded:

[image]

Here's the `NetworkManager.conf` file content:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Following these indications: [No wired connection - Wired unmanaged ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039233/no-wired-connection-wired-unmanaged-ubuntu-18-04)

I tried to put `managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
and run

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

followed by a system reboot.
But the problem still persists.

Modifying the `01-network-manager-all.yaml` file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
#Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  #renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.7/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

to

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  #renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: trye
      #dhcp4: no
      #addresses: [192.168.1.7/24]
      #gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      #nameservers:
      #  addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

made the wired connection working again.

What happened due to this Ubuntu 18.04 package upgrade?

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NetworkManager**

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and change "managed" back to false.

Assure that `/etc/network/interfaces` only contains the following active lines:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Set your `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` back to:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Then configure your wired connection using the NetworkManager GUI.

Comment: I checked everything and it corresponds to what I've already set. Anyway, thanks for these guidelines

Comment: This answer is right on.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` file that you posted is not the default netplan configuration that is provided by the Ubuntu desktop installer.  The most likely explanation for this behavior is that you edited (with an editor or through some software) this file, and after applying the latest updates you rebooted, causing Network Manager to respect the new config which told it not to manage the wired ethernet interface.

Comment: As far as I know I didn't do any thing, apart from upgrading the ubuntu packages

Answer (score 0):

I have try and it works.

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```