# ExpressVPN disconnects the entire wired connection upon disconnecting

Tags: vpn

I don't know where to find the solution of this, but Expressvpn running in Google Chrome Ubuntu 20.04 as an extension disconnects the wired connection completely when pressing "Disconnect VPN". This did not happen in Ubuntu 18.04. Any chance of preventing that, or should Express VPN people reprogram their software?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and faced same problem 
this solution worked for me:

- Edit NetworkManager.conf `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` change `managed=false` to `managed=true`
- Restart network manager `sudo service network-manager restart`

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039233/no-wired-connection-wired-unmanaged-ubuntu-18-04)