# Livepatch is not available for this system (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, canonical-livepatch

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 last night, logged into Ubuntu One, after which Livepatch was working as intended, without any issues.
This morning I went into *Software & Updates* to check on some added repos, when I noticed in the Livepatch tab that it's not enabled.

[image]

The system tray shield icon is showing a check mark, meaning that Livepatch should be enabled.

[image]

What may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install GNOME Online Accounts first with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue - and I'm logged into my Ubuntu account in Ubuntu 20.04 and "live-patch" on and 20 updates are available ...but it still complains about no internet connection (and all internet is working fine)?

Comment: SOLVED! I did both... the top 2 answers in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039233/no-wired-connection-wired-unmanaged-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Check the [official link](https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/?user_type=ubuntu-user) for more details and activation about livepatch. You may need to login with your Ubuntu One account.