# Ubuntu ethernet became unmanaged after update

Tags: upgrade, ethernet

After one of Ubuntu updates I got my Ethernet connection unmanaged and not working when OS is loaded.

I tried different solutions, posted in internet:
[No wired connection - Wired unmanaged ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039233/no-wired-connection-wired-unmanaged-ubuntu-18-04)
https://superuser.com/questions/1429490/unmanaged-network-manager-in-ubuntu
https://forum.linuxconfig.org/t/wired-unmanaged-ubuntu-desktop-issue/1574
[network manager says "device not managed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)
[Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)

Neither ow them worked.

Also I tried to activate connection using `nmtui` tool, but I got following error:

```
││ Could not activate connection:       │  │  
││ Connection 'Wired connection 1' is   │  │  
││ not available on device eth0 because │  │ 
││ device is strictly unmanaged         │  │
```

To provide more context, here is the relevant system configuration information:

```
~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[logging]
level=TRACE

~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf 
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=none

~$ cat /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf 
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
cat: '/etc/netplan/*.yaml': No such file or directory

~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 06
       serial: 50:e5:49:3c:26:4e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:17 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fbdff000-fbdfffff memory:fbdf8000-fbdfbfff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY
       vendor: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:01.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 31
       serial: c0:4a:00:01:19:7f
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=sundance latency=64 maxlatency=10 mingnt=10 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:19 ioport:ef00(size=128) memory:fbcff000-fbcff1ff memory:fbc00000-fbc0ffff
```

Please note both Ethernet adapters are shown as `network DISABLED` in `lshw` output.

**Ubuntu version** (desktop)

```
NAME="Ubuntu"  
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
```

Also I tried to load previous version of the kernel. Internet worked well there.
But after I ran `apt upgrade` and rebooted machine - internet became broken there too.

So, for now I completely have no idea what to look further. Any ideas and suggestions are very welcome.

**PS:**
I got internet connection working by manual run operation `sudo dhclient`. After that my Ethernet adapter became IP address and internet started working.
Also it causes that both my Ethernet adapters are not `DISABLED` anymore in `lshw` command output.

But the device is still unmanaged. No internet icon in the GUI. No settings available in GUI for wired connection.

So the question is still open:
How can I get my wired connection managed back?

Comment: Set `managed=false` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, and clear out (empty file) `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`. Also, edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: @heynnema I made the changes you're recommending. It gave no visible effect. I.e. network device is still unmanaged.
Also I added output of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. In fact `netplan` folder is empty on my machine.

Comment: Did you reboot? Desktop or Server installation? What version Ubuntu? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: @heynnema I rebooted machine after configuration changes. Ubuntu version: 20.04.1 LTS Desktop (I also added this information to question). And I added the output of `lshw` in there.
Btw, initially after reboot my both Ethernet adapters are listed as `DISABLED` in `lshw` output. But when I run `dhclient` - they start working and the mark `DISABLED` is not shown anymore in `lshw` output.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: does a connection show up in  

nm-connection-editor

if so delete it and let in reinstall.

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk Are both ethernet adapters connected with cables? Are you using eth0 or eth1? Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Please describe your wiring from the ethernet port, all the way to the router/hub.

Comment: @heynnemma I tried plugging to any: eth0 and eth1. The behavior was the same. Current wiring is: eth0 is plugged via cat 5, cable length is 1.2 meter, connected to router (TP-LINK AC1200) at the other end. eth1 is unplugged.

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk I almost missed your last comment, as you misspelled my user name. Anyway, I suspect that you have an external problem... ie: cable or router. Do you have any cat 5e or cat 6 cables that you can try? Have you rebooted the router?

Comment: @heynnema sorry for misspelling your name. I don't think it's a cable or a router problem. Internet becomes working in unmanaged mode after manual run `dhclient`. I.e. everything is good on a physical level. Also everything is working good when I'm booting another OS on same machine (Ubuntu from USB, or Windows). The problem is that ethernet is unmanaged even though it is working.

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk But... your `lshw` shows link=no, AND you're using a cat 5 cable. Very possible cable/router problem.

Comment: @heynnema I would agree :) But how and why it works with the other operating systems? Btw, I tried different cables, and both eth0 and eth1. Any setup works fine. But in one of my ubuntu setup it's getting unmanaged...

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. If it works there, I'd reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema sure, internet works when boots from Live USB. Ok, thank you for your support. I'll try to dig it more detailed at a free time. The problem is not blocking, it has a workaround. And it's actually very interesting what went wrong with current setup.

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk I updated my answer.

Answer (score 14):

Create a file in /etc/netplan:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/networkmanager.yaml
```

or

```
sudo pico /etc/netplan/networkmanager.yaml
```

Place this content in that file, keeping the exact same indentation, spacing, and no tabs:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then, in `terminal`:

```
sudo netplan generate

sudo netplan apply

reboot
```

Then use the NetworkManager GUI tools to configure your "Wired Connection".

**Update #1:**

When booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, ethernet works fine. Will need to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi @heynnema sorry for being off for the long time. The netplan installation and configuration actually didn't help.
The current networking state is actually unstable: Sometimes after reboot network connection is managed and network does work. Sometimes after reboot the network connection is unmanaged and it requires running 'dhclient' to get network available.

Comment: I had the DISABLED issue. `netplan generate` showed a typo in one of the yaml. I don't remember ever touching it, but seems that was the cause

Comment: This solution worked well for me, except that when I go into settings and change IPv4 Method from Automatic (DHCP) to Manual, the manual connection isn't persistent across reboots and it changes back to automatic. Any advice?

Comment: @guttermonk What values are you setting in the Manual panel?

Comment: @heynnema I set the address and netmask and checked the box for "Use this connection only for resources on its network." That said, I think I just found a work-around - I created a new connection and set it to connect automatically. I just tested it and it survived a reboot. It looks like any edits on the original netplan-enp8s0 connection aren't persistent, even just unchecking the connect automatically box. It goes right back to checked after reboot. Must be a permissions issue somewhere.

Comment: @guttermonk It's difficult to further diagnose your problem using comments. Please start a new question and describe your problem. Include a listing of all of the .yaml files in /etc/netplan, and a screenshot of the manual network panel. Ping me when that's done.

Answer (score 10):

I found this post, and tried many of the same things without any luck. What was successful for me:

```
nmcli n on
```

Now the previously managed devices are managed again.

Comment: thanks, saved me after hours of trying weird stuff.

Comment: Thanks, it works for Rocky Linux 8.5
`sudo nmcli networking on`

Comment: thank you, i wasted 2h trying other stuff. this fixed it for me