# Ethernet device is strictly unmanaged on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: network-manager, ethernet

Trying to enable Ethernet using nmtui on my laptop that is connected using a USB to Ethernet adapter fails with error "Ethernet connection is not available because device is strictly unmanaged".

How can I enable it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu ethernet became unmanaged after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290471/ubuntu-ethernet-became-unmanaged-after-update)

Comment: I'm new down here. I was cracking my head with these thing in Ubuntu 22.02 and the solution down below works great: [<a>https://superuser.com/questions/1429490/unmanaged-network-manager-in-ubuntu/1632034</a>](https://askubuntu.com/users/961802/joshua-johns) Thanks Joshua!!!: [<a>https://askubuntu.com/users/961802/joshua-johns</a>](https://superuser.com/users/1090963/joshua-johns) [<a>https://superuser.com/users/1090963/joshua-johns</a>](https://superuser.com/users/1090963/joshua-johns)