# Kernel upgrade to ubuntu 22.04 - lost alx driver and cannot get network to work

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 22.04, atheros

I have a desktop computer with an onboard nic and no wifi. The cable + connection was tested with another ubuntu PC to confirm that it works.

After upgrading ubuntu 20.04 -> 22.04 I had no network.

I got NetworkManager and netplan with the upgrade and followed the steps at [Ubuntu ethernet became unmanaged after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290471/ubuntu-ethernet-became-unmanaged-after-update).
Nmcli shows that my ethernet device is unmanaged.

But not only does nmcli show that my device is unmanaged, but lshw shows that my device is UNCLAIMED indicating that there is no driver.

My computer was missing the alx driver for my card, but I cannot get it since I have no network. So I tried dowloading it from the Ubuntu live disk 22.04, but it doesnt work since the kernel was different. I also tried to download this package that contains alx.ko;

https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/lunar/main/security/linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-32-generic since
My kernel is 6.2.0-36-generic but I get unkown symbol error in dmesg indicating that it was compiled for another version.

How do I get networking to work? I tried it all! Even my two usb wifi dongles but they have the same issue.

uname -a

```
Linux lindesk005 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

nmcli

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         vethb268557
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         86:xx
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::8451:c4ff:fe97:ea16/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

modprobe

```
# modprobe alx
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'alx': Invalid argument


#dmesg

[  814.937013] alx: disagrees about version of symbol alloc_etherdev_mqs
[  814.937016] alx: Unknown symbol alloc_etherdev_mqs (err -22)
[  814.937040] alx: disagrees about version of symbol _raw_spin_lock_irqsave
[  814.937041] alx: Unknown symbol _raw_spin_lock_irqsave (err -22)
[  814.937061] alx: disagrees about version of symbol request_threaded_irq
[  814.937062] alx: Unknown symbol request_threaded_irq (err -22)
[  814.937084] alx: disagrees about version of symbol pcie_get_readrq
[  814.937084] alx: Unknown symbol pcie_get_readrq (err -22)
[  814.937103] alx: disagrees about version of symbol napi_schedule_prep
[  814.937104] alx: Unknown symbol napi_schedule_prep (err -22)
[  814.937107] alx: disagrees about version of symbol _raw_spin_unlock
[  814.937108] alx: Unknown symbol _raw_spin_unlock (err -22)
[ 1041.584553] alx: disagrees about version of symbol alloc_etherdev_mqs
[ 1041.584555] alx: Unknown symbol alloc_etherdev_mqs (err -22)
[ 1041.584580] alx: disagrees about version of symbol _raw_spin_lock_irqsave
[ 1041.584581] alx: Unknown symbol _raw_spin_lock_irqsave (err -22)
[ 1041.584602] alx: disagrees about version of symbol request_threaded_irq
[ 1041.584603] alx: Unknown symbol request_threaded_irq (err -22)
[ 1041.584624] alx: disagrees about version of symbol pcie_get_readrq
[ 1041.584625] alx: Unknown symbol pcie_get_readrq (err -22)
[ 1041.584645] alx: disagrees about version of symbol napi_schedule_prep
[ 1041.584646] alx: Unknown symbol napi_schedule_prep (err -22)
[ 1041.584649] alx: disagrees about version of symbol _raw_spin_unlock
[ 1041.584650] alx: Unknown symbol _raw_spin_unlock (err -22)
```

modinfo

```
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     693BCA3A05C3F4A43DE0D3F
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E0B1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E0A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           alx
vermagic:       6.2.0-36-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        06:39:3A:13:39:AD:92:C5:9C:A8:72:A7:8C:35:47:2E:9B:AE:55:63
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      AB:0B:03:DC:8F:22:20:C9:F9:B8:69:04:A8:72:6F:0B:78:00:91:37:
        DF:EC:B9:EC:33:D0:92:4E:67:B9:C0:79:E5:CF:37:65:A9:D0:3D:31:
        79:A5:78:9C:E0:A1:31:2F:3A:2C:A2:70:FB:55:50:CB:F1:BA:92:20:
        CE:1D:3B:5F:01:0B:62:81:A5:62:92:9E:37:59:0F:32:FC:40:46:50:
        EF:BB:84:3C:E0:86:05:0D:D2:8D:05:85:E3:AF:4E:CC:52:AC:3A:95:
        C0:22:2F:DA:AE:FF:F2:F6:DD:0B:F1:CB:90:96:59:4A:67:3A:63:80:
        91:BE:A9:51:20:43:7E:FF:72:97:92:BB:26:6A:42:EC:F0:B5:2D:22:
        D0:6D:CD:93:27:AE:97:1D:5D:9E:6B:9D:2D:5D:95:69:74:7E:9F:8B:
        B8:38:81:AC:17:50:6F:EC:62:5C:7E:A7:98:8A:97:A1:C1:80:D3:FB:
        6B:A5:68:3B:83:45:2B:39:5E:82:2F:CC:46:08:B8:0C:76:E7:B6:09:
        FE:D8:E0:6E:55:F1:A7:8D:B9:AE:FB:A3:06:3D:F6:63:97:3F:7A:78:
        92:C7:BD:18:57:67:A4:E8:7E:FC:C6:63:5B:17:12:8D:47:AC:46:79:
        F0:5D:EE:22:3B:9C:29:C2:BB:85:EA:3C:61:48:A7:4B:4E:17:2F:C3:
        0C:D5:84:39:80:30:E3:6D:B5:6A:CB:3B:47:9C:50:20:E5:24:5C:05:
        3D:3E:94:D1:1A:73:84:B1:20:67:99:DD:22:42:CB:8C:E1:19:AF:BC:
        E4:3F:FD:F3:30:61:B3:91:77:BD:1A:4D:54:10:74:F1:59:4D:D3:4D:
        37:2D:E4:0D:1C:8A:CA:AB:CF:E8:0C:56:AE:48:52:F1:26:E1:CA:BD:
        F3:35:76:25:3A:73:5F:D9:B3:26:54:1A:06:F1:EC:E7:B0:76:A5:AC:
        3D:8D:B9:5A:12:6C:89:07:0F:67:04:1C:80:64:2D:E6:79:89:AD:E8:
        3F:73:63:1A:BE:6C:21:BD:DE:7E:C9:E0:5B:3D:7A:80:18:44:0B:30:
        02:60:16:B7:B6:44:CA:BF:70:4B:94:0B:EF:EC:32:9E:98:62:7B:00:
        44:D2:13:6E:35:63:76:81:ED:3A:D9:FC:3C:E8:59:C2:60:0B:64:10:
        9B:22:19:88:01:CB:DA:05:3C:C0:53:AC:98:9A:03:A7:7E:2F:28:14:
        6E:A5:AA:96:EC:5D:0C:56:B2:FC:18:23:B9:45:50:51:C2:55:FC:61:
        85:C5:F7:B3:C4:90:B6:CE:20:9E:77:EB:6E:C2:CD:09:AA:94:C1:0D:
        CE:19:84:F7:F0:85:E4:DD:43:5E:EF:10
```

lspci

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
    Region 0: Memory at ec400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 4096 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- AttnBtn+ AttnInd+ PwrInd+ RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 10.000W
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/16 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [d8] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=0 offset=00002000
        PBA: BAR=0 offset=00003000
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP- SDES+ TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Capabilities: [180 v1] Device Serial Number ff-b6-e8-95-b8-85-84-ff
    Kernel modules: alx
```

lshw

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ec200000-ec3fffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ec400000-ec43ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I downloaded the wrong kernel version -32 instead of -36
The following command gives the proper command and hash to download a package on an external computer:

```
sudo apt-get download  --print-uris linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

and then when downloaded on an internet enabled computer, go back to the original machine and do:

```
dpkg -i linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-36-generic_6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1_amd64.deb
```